# Why is a word on x86 only 16 bits instead of 32 bits?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

All the current x86 processors are 32-bit processors, but the wordsize is 16-bits.
Most 32-bit processors have a wordsize of 32-bits.

See

> b Byte (8–bit)
>
> w Word (16–bit)
>
> l Long (32–bit) (default)
>
> q Quadword (64–bit)

on page 18 in [x86 Assembly Language Reference Manual 1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-5477/817-5477.pdf),

> Table 1-5 16-bit (word) General Registers

in  [x86 Assembly Language
Reference Manual 2](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse548/05wi/files/x86-reference-long.pdf)

Comment: Historical reasons for compatibility. Intel didn't want to make people change their code when they switched from 16 to 32 and then to 64 bits.

Comment: _"All the current x86 processors are 32-bit processors"_ There was a time when that wasn't the case, and the terminology remains from back then.

Comment: All current x86 processors are x86-64, capable of running in 64-bit mode.  They basically don't have "a" single native word-size, and can comfortably / efficiently access data at any power-of-2 size from 1 to 32 bytes, even unaligned.